# Concurrent updates to shared database by microservices .. Lost Updates

Tags: database, microservices

[Flow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMLU1.png)

Our microservices are calling third party service, using REST API to access (read/update) same record in shared database

**Use case 1: Same microservice making multiple calls to access same record**

- A customer bought 10 units of a product A
- Another customer bought 5 units of same product A
- 2 calls made by UI API to end point /decrementProduct within few milliseconds
- Both calls may end up reading the same inventory count for product A at that time, and both will decrement the purchase units for product A, based on the inventory count they reads.

Example:

- Inventory Count before calls: 10
- Call 1 decrement 5 units from 10, and updated back 5 as current inventory count.
- Call 2 decrement 2 units from 10, and updated back 8 as current inventory count.
- Inventory Count after calls: 8
- Correct Inventory Count after calls should be: 3

**Use case 2: Multiple microservices making multiple calls to access same record**
The problem explained in use case 1 will exacerbate in this case, due to number of calls to update same record in a database.

**Edit: 13-April-2021**
The shared database is exposed to our microservices using REST API and we don't have any control over the physical database and the exposed REST API, to implement any transactions or locking mechanism at the database level.

Comment: fortunately databases implement transactions..... https://zongwb.medium.com/distributed-transactions-in-a-microservice-architecture-271ec1cb235

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database you are using but traditional relational databases like: oracle, postgresql, mysql, db2, etc... already address these kind of issues using locks in the records that are being updated to ensure that there are not concurrent problems.

I mean, if you open a transaction where you read a value and then update it, There won't be any problem because if you try to update a row in database with different version number that the one that is currently set (an outdated version), The database w'ont let update it

Comment: Thanks for the response Argente. I should have mentioned in my post that we don't have control over database, as it belongs to a third party service. We just have CRUD endpoints available as REST API for this database.